# How to build valid PUT rest call that requires CSRF token

Tags: vb.net, rest, put

I get the "400" error when i do this PUT call (vb.net).

What am i doing wrong?

```
  Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://localhost:8444/api/route/1802/state"), HttpWebRequest) 
  wRequest.Method = "PUT"
  wRequest.ContentType = "text/plain"
  Dim stringData As String = "STOP"
  Dim data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData)
  wRequest.ContentLength = data.Length
  Dim newStream = wRequest.GetRequestStream()
  newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
  newStream.Close()
  wResponse = DirectCast(wRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

The last line throw the 400.

[this call doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4wQj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

X-CSRF-Token was missing.

1. Do a GET and store the CSRF token from the response.

   ```
   If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_csrfToken))
       _csrfToken = wResponse.Headers("X-CSRF-Token")
   End If
   ```
2. Add the token to PUT request before the "GetResponse"

   ```
   If(not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_csrfToken))
       wRequest.Headers("X-CSRF-Token") = _csrfToken
   End If
   ```

Note: X-CSRF-Token have the lifespan of the session.